# Android Room framework throws illegalStateException: trying to open already closed database

Tags: android, database

I followed the sample code provide by google [here](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/room.html) for the Room library for storage.
I was executing queries on a separate thread and was joining every query thread so once one thread has completed then only other will run having thought that it would solve the problem but it didn't. Now I'm running queries on the main thread to make it work for now.
Can anyone tell me how to use this library using separate thread for each query.
My query is like this -

```
    public static void insertUserDetails(Context context, User user, QueryResultCallback listener) {
        Runnable r = () -> {
            try {
                long id = AppDatabase.getDatabase(context).userModel().insert(user);
                getHandler().post(() -> listener.onSuccess(id));
            } catch (Exception e) {
                getHandler().post(() -> listener.onFailure(e));
            }
        };
        runQuery(r);
    }
```

And the runQuery method -

```
private static void runQuery(Runnable runnable) {
        Thread t = new Thread(runnable, DATABASE_THREAD);
        t.start();
        try {
            t.join();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: This occurs when you performing some transaction after commit your transaction.

Comment: @VindhyaPratapSingh I'm using Dao for transactions.

Answer (score 0):

To perform insert operation with Room you can use [Android WorkManager](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager/) to run tasks on a worker thread and avoid running tasks on main/ui thread. Moreover, check this kotlin sample code from [Google samples](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-sunflower/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/google/samples/apps/sunflower/workers/SeedDatabaseWorker.kt), wherein, a one of [bulk insert](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-sunflower/blob/0cd985c45691488933ab9640d49ceca631c597ad/app/src/main/java/com/google/samples/apps/sunflower/workers/SeedDatabaseWorker.kt#L42) is done taking input from a JSON file. Further, while building the DB the work is sanctioned via WorkManager, [as here](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-sunflower/blob/0cd985c45691488933ab9640d49ceca631c597ad/app/src/main/java/com/google/samples/apps/sunflower/data/AppDatabase.kt#L54). Let me know if you need more simpler or Java code to understand how to accomplish the insert operation on a worker thread.